# Centering an image in a div horizontally not knowing the width

Tags: css, image, centering

I'm trying to center an image in a div without having control over the image width. You can see the example of the featured listings here:

http://citylightsrealtygroup.com/

Since this is gong to be updated by the admin and I cant control. The code looks like this yet its not centering its still lined up to the left edge:

```
.feature_thumb img{
    width:auto;
    height:100%;
    display:block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

Its much better with the aspect ratio of the thumb to set the height to auto and let the width overflow instead of the opposite. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: There are so many questions on stack overflow asking how to do this. You need to do your research before you ask a question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using way too big images there that will load painfully slow on slower bandwith; thumbnails should be generated in order to prevent that. I suggest you to generate them programatically or by using timthumb - https://code.google.com/p/timthumb/

When you use it, the script will automatically center, crop and resize the image. You just have to specify width and height

```
<img src="timthumb.php?src=IMAGE_SOURCE&w=WIDTH&h=HEIGHT" />
```

Comment: One is way to huge and I wanted to remove it when I was done testing. I wanted to try and get the code working for worst case scenario.

Will this script crop from the center? Also the aspect ratios of the pics that have been uploaded thus far is all over the place taken from different cameras. Will it take that into consideration?

Comment: Aspect radio in this case doesn't matter. Here you have the example how this library works:
Original picture: http://arkadiazary.eu.hostingasp.pl/Storage/Produkty/10_of_Clubs___Catta_by_kenket.jpg

Cropped: http://arkadiazary.eu.hostingasp.pl/timthumb.php?src=Storage/Produkty/10_of_Clubs___Catta_by_kenket.jpg&w=300&h=200

Comment: Pablo, Thanks for the info trying to implement it now.

Comment: No problem ;) But please mark your question as answered to distinguish it from unresolved.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like this question could use a little cleaning up.  You might want to post a follow up to ask about some of the other issues you mention.  But to answer the question at hand, about centering an image in its parent... instead of setting a CSS property on the image itself, set `text-align` to `center` on the **image's parent** `div`.

Comment: Ive tried that with it not working here's the code for the container div:

.feature_thumb{
 width:127px;
 height:98px;
 border: 1px solid #999999;
 text-align:center;
 overflow:hidden;
}

Comment: I think you need to edit your question with a description of exactly what you are trying to accomplish and a small (but complete) example of how you are trying to accomplish it - both the HTML and CSS in this case.  I'm assuming that the reason my answer "doesn't work" is because you aren't simply "trying to center an image in a div".  Instead, you have an image that you want to scale and then "clip" by wrapping in a smaller div... is that right?